# An isolated point in spectrum of a normal operator is an eigenvalue.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $T$ is a normal operator on a Hilbert space and $\lambda$ is an isolated point in $\sigma(T)$.

Assume $\lambda$ isn't an eigenvalue.

Since $T-\lambda$ and $T^*-\lambda^*$ have the same kernel,  $T^*-\lambda^*$ is also injective. Then by the non-invertibility, $T-\lambda$ must not be surjective. Therefore there are unit vectors $x_j$ such that  $\|(T-\lambda)x_j\|<1/n$.

Then I got  stuck. What should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but I don't see how you could use that $\lambda$ is an approximate eigenvalue to conclude that it is an eigenvalue.

What you can use, due to $T$ being normal, is the continuous funcional calculus. Take $f$ to be continuous on $\sigma(T)$, with $f(\lambda)=1$ and $f=0$ on $\sigma(T)\setminus\{\lambda\}$. Then $P=f(T)$ is a nonzero projection, and since $$t\,f(t)=\lambda\,f(t),$$
you get
$$
TP=\lambda P.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually I knew the standard way is to use functional calculus, but I was wondering whether there is a simpler way to show it, since the proposition does not seem that complicated.

Comment: Hello @Martin Argerami how is $P$ defined? Is the equality $tf(t)=\lambda f(t)$ follows from the function f you defined?

Comment: @Bestmat: as the answer says, one uses functional calculus to define $P$ as $f(T)$.